# error: unknown/unsupported geography heirarchy, when querying Census tracts

Tags: r, census

I'm following `rcensusapi`'s [guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/censusapi/censusapi.pdf) on retrieving data for retrieving Census tract-level data. Here's my code.

```
getCensus(
  name = "acs/acs5/cprofile",
  vintage = 2018,
  key = Sys.getenv("CENSUS_API"),
  vars = c("NAME","CP03_2014_2018_062E"),
  region = "tract:*",
  regionin = "state:12+county:033"
)
```

But when I run this code I get this error.

```
 Error in apiCheck(req) : 
  The Census Bureau returned the following error message:
 error: unknown/unsupported geography heirarchy
```

Comment: It's not an R problem; the table doesn't exist at the tract level. From the [API docs](https://api.census.gov/data/2018/acs/acs5/cprofile.html): "The comparison profiles include the following geographies: nation, all states (including DC and Puerto Rico), all metropolitan areas, all congressional districts, all counties and all places with a population of 5,000 or more." Do you need the comparison tables, or could you calculate the same things from the 5-year ACS detailed tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This similar query seemed to work to give a county-wide number.

```
getCensus(
  name = "acs/acs5/cprofile",
  vintage = 2018,
  key = Sys.getenv("CENSUS_API"),
  vars = c("NAME","CP03_2014_2018_062E"),
  region = "county:033",
  # region = "county",  # to get all counties in FL
  # region = "congressional district",  # to get all congressional districts in FL
  regionin = "state:12"
)

#  state county                     NAME CP03_2014_2018_062E
#1    12    033 Escambia County, Florida               49286
```

It's also possible to get the values for all Florida counties or congressional districts with the alternate filters above.

But unfortunately I don't think it's possible to get tract-level detail for this particular query.

https://api.census.gov/data/2018/acs/acs5/cprofile.html
https://api.census.gov/data/2018/acs/acs5/cprofile/examples.html

Judging by the help at those links, it doesn't look like this survey is available at the tract level. Here are the listed geographical levels for the `region` parameter from [here](https://api.census.gov/data/2018/acs/acs5/cprofile/geography.html). (Also, as @ThetaFC noted in the comments, it's possible to query this list directly using `listCensusMetadata(name = "acs/acs5/cprofile", vintage = 2018, type = "geography")`.)

[image]

Comment: Good answer other than the question was relative to ```vintage=2018```.  You can also run this to see available geography for your particular dataset of interest: ```listCensusMetadata(name = "acs/acs5/cprofile", vintage = 2018, type = "geography")```

Comment: Thanks, updated my links to 2018 -- didn't notice that the site nav landed me on 2017 pages...